# DataDog monitor containers stuck in restart-loops

Tags: docker, containers, monitoring, amazon-ecs, datadog

Trying to monitor a repeatedly crushing container inside an AWS ECS cluster monitored by DataDog.

Created a demo app which crushes after 120 second (ECS tries to run it non-stop).

**Cant figure out how to see if its stuck in restart loop like this app**

Current DataDog metric :

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey..still looking for a solution

Comment: hmmm..i guess im alone here

Comment: This isn't a software development question, so it probably hasn't got much traction on Stack Overflow. A better place for it would have been [sf].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess i found something that will work..

Created a monitor based of events

[image]